# How to move a text on the Y axis

Tags: html, css

As my jsfiddle shows, I am trying to move the span tag further down so that the rest of the paragraph text can stand in the middle of it.
https://jsfiddle.net/9r81ry8c/1/

html:

```
<div>
  <p> This <span>is</span> awesome </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
span{
  font-size: 60px;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
}
```

An example is the same when we put a horizontal line in the middle of text where it looks like: - This -. Well obviously in my case, the lines are now text paragraph.
How can I move the span tag to the vertically down to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

CSS `vertical-align` property is for exactly this situation:

```
span{
    font-size: 60px;
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
 p {
    display: inline-block; /* see edit below */
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9r81ry8c/14/

Your "is" is now larger than the other text so by setting this text to "middle" causes the other text by implication to also be centred on the horizontal axis.

A possible side effect of this is that the centreing is not done with the **visible** height of the letters but with the size of the letter glyph, so you will notice that perhaps the  `i` of the `is` is not in line but it *is* in line as a glyph box, even though the letter may not *fill* that glyph box.

**EDIT**:

It is worth noting that `vertical-align` will only apply to **inline**,
**inline-block** or **inline-table** elements. So if your vertical alignment isn't working check / confirm that the element you are aligning (its immediate parent such as your `<p>` in your example) is set to one of these `display` types, listed above.

A very [good read about Vertical align can be found here](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/).

Comment: Indeed. I tried that before and it actually works  as in your fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/9r81ry8c/6/ .For some reason in my wordpress site this does not work.
But I just tried using vertical-align sub and it works perfectly on both jsfiddle and WordPress.
https://jsfiddle.net/9r81ry8c/8/

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I have updated my answer with something I think will explain your WP behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`Display` as `inline-block` for `span`. `span` tag further down from `p` tag so for that you need to change your translate value from `minus(-)` to `plus(+)`

```css
span{
 font-size: 60px;
 transform: translateY(20%);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p> This <span>is</span> awesome </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try vertical-align prop like below

```
span {
    font-size: 60px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1;
}
p {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1;
}
```

Comment: `line-height: 1;` ?

Comment: it's for setting the line-height as 100% of font-size

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `transform` only on an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model.

[Here your updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/9r81ry8c/4/)

So to use transform, first you need to use a positive value then you must set display: inline-block for youe [span].
To be fully compatible I suggest you to add even Safari and IE syntax

```
span{
    font-size: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    -ms-transform: translate(10%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(10%); /* Safari */
    transform: translateY(10%); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your style check this.

```
span{
    font-size: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

working fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/9r81ry8c/7/

Comment: @LoneRanger.Thanks it also works.Is there any way I can play around with every second word of the text in the div? I am trying to use pseudo selector :second-word(2n) but it's not working